# Replacing HTML String & Avoiding Tags (regex)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, tags

I'm trying to use JS to replace a specific string within a string that contains html tags+attributes and styles while avoiding the inner side of the tags to be read or matched (and keep the original tags in the text).

for example, I want `<span> this is span text </span>` to be become: `<span> this is s<span class="found">pan</span> text </span>` when the keyword is "pan"

I tried using regex with that ..
My regex so far:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp("([^<\"][a-zA-Z0-9\"'\=;:]*)(" + search + ")([a-zA-Z0-9\"'\=;:]*[^>\"])", 'ig'), "$1<span class='found'>$2</span>$3"));
```

This regex only fails in cases like `<span class="myclass"> span text </span>` when the search="p", the result:

```
<s<span class="found">p</span>an class="myclass"> s<span class="found">p</span>an text</s<span class="found">p</span>an>
```

*this topic should help anyone who seeks to find a match and replace the matched string while avoiding strings surrounded by specific characters to be replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As thg435 say, the good way to deal with html content is to use the DOM.

But if you want to avoid something in a replace, you can match that you want to avoid first and replace it by itself.

Example to avoid html tags:

```
var text = '<span class="myclass"> span text </span>';

function callback(p1, p2) {
    return ((p2==undefined)||p2=='')?p1:'<span class="found">'+p1+'</span>';
}

var result = text.replace(/<[^>]+>|(p)/g, callback);

alert(result);
```

Comment: I recommend this method, it is faster as it has no major loops .. thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps, however keep in mind that the callback function is called at each occurence

Comment: oops; this method has a problem with chrome, it mis-executes the regex somehow it replaces spaces and other tags too